# Get string from current URL

Tags: asp.net, string, url, substring

I am writing an asp.net MVC Application. I have the application send a request to FreeAgent and if the request is successful a code is returned in the redirect of the URL. 
For example this is a copy of a successful URL.

```
{
http://localhost:3425/FreeAgent/Home?code=144B2ymEKw3JfB9EDPIqCGeWKYLb9IKc-ABI6SZ0o&state=
}
```

They have added the ?code=144B2ymEKw3JfB9EDPIqCGeWKYLb9IKc-ABI6SZ0o&state= to my URL
I need the bit after the ?code= and before &state=

I can use this to get the URL

```
string code = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

but I need help extracting the code from this

edit:
The code will be different each time it is run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `System.Uri` and `System.Web.HttpUtility` classes

```
string uri = "http://localhost:3425/FreeAgent/Home?code=144B2ymEKw3JfB9EDPIqCGeWKYLb9IKc-ABI6SZ0o&state=";
string queryString = new System.Uri(uri).Query;
var queryDictionary = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
```

Then the value of the `code` query parameter will be available in `queryDictionary["code"]`

Comment: So continuing from your example how would i just put:  string code = queryDictionary["code"] ?

Comment: Yeah, exactly.  You can access the query parameters like a dictionary and set them to other variables or do whatever you need.